# How to trigger the Dark Wanderer's three secrets in this week's tavern brawl?

Tags: hearthstone

The Dark Wanderer in this week's Tavern Brawl starts the game with three secrets. I played a Annoyotron, triggering one of the secrets (Play a minion with Taunt - changes all minions' attacks to 1).

What are the other two secrets' triggers and effects? I am given to understand that triggering all three secrets results in nothing interesting happening at all, certainly not a secret cow level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a total of 10 possible secrets, 3 of which are randomly chosen each game.
Those are:

- Visions of the Amazon - Secret: When your opponent summons a minion
  with Battlecry, Summon a Mirror Image for both players.
- Visions of
  the Assassin - Secret: When your opponent summons a minion with
  Stealth, All minions equip a dagger.
- Visions of the Barbarian -
  Secret: When your opponent summons a minion with Charge, THUNDER
  FURY!
- Visions of the Crusader - Secret: When your opponent summons a
  minion with Taunt, change all minions' attacks to 1.
- Visions of the
  Necromancer - Secret: When your opponent summons a minion with
  Deathrattle, destroy it.
- Visions of the Sorcerer - Secret: When your
  opponent summons a minion with Spell Damage, Summon 2 Guardians.
- Visions of Fate - Secret: When your opponent takes lethal damage...
  save him.
- Visions of Hate - Secret: When both heroes have 15 or less
  Health, BRAWL!
- Visions of Valor - Secret: When your opponent summons
  a Legendary minion, give all minions Windfury.
- Visions of Knowledge -
  Secret: When your opponent's hand has 9 or more cards, reduce the
  cost of all cards in both hands to (1).

Source: http://www.hearthpwn.com/news/2134-the-dark-wanderer-is-this-weeks-tavern-brawl-and